# How to get all nodes of a RadTreeNode?

Tags: c#, winforms, telerik, treeview

In a RadTreeNode children are stored in Nodes. If filter is set, they're holding only matching nodes. How can I get all nodes regardless of the filter?

Comment: I don't see a filter property.  Only a visible and expand.  See : https://docs.telerik.com/devtools/winforms/api/html/t_telerik_wincontrols_ui_radtreenode.htm

Comment: yes, you're right. indeed there's a SetFilter function which sets the Visible property of nodes based on a string. Nodes then returns only visible nodes. I need a list of all nodes regardless of their visibility.

Comment: So what is your question?  You still get all the nodes even if they are not visible.

Comment: will check and see whether it really returns all nodes regardless of their visibility. thx

Comment: Indeed RadTreeView has a member called Filter and if this member is set, only matching items are included in Nodes. If you set this member to "", the Nodes will include all items again.